# Big-O notation confusion regarding logarithms

Tags: notation, algorithms

I've been doing a series of problems regarding big-O notation, and I was under the impression that I had a grasp on it until I found this one:
'Is the statement $(\log n)^2+{1\over 30}\log n \in O((\log n)^2)$ true or false?'

I did the following steps in an attempt to compute this:
$$
\begin{align}
(\log n)^2+{\log n\over 30} &\leq |\log n|^2 + {1\over 30}|\log n|\\
                                      &\leq |\log n|^2 + {1\over 30}|\log n|^2\\
                                      &= {31\over 30}|\log n|^2
\end{align}
$$
However, in testing with Desmos, I found that this was false, and that the original statement is in turn false. What am I missing, in regards to my process? I clearly have some misconception but I can't necesserily spot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only error you made is where you have written
$$
|\log n| \le |\log n|^2 \tag{1}
$$
in your second line. This is not true **for all $\pmb n$**, since for some small values of $n$, $|\log n| > |\log n|^2$. However, big-O notation is about capturing the behavior of the functions for **large values of $\pmb n$** (or whatever the parameter is, more generally). So while $(1)$ is not true for every $n$, it is sufficient for big-O that it be true for all $n$ sufficiently large, say for $n > 10$.

In conclusion, if you write "assume $n> 10$" right at the top of your proof, then your entire proof is correct, and you can conclude the given statement is true.